# Can't get value from SELECT

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple code that is working fine on my Google Chrome but fails to run on IE 8. When an option is selected the value always comes up empty.

```
<form target="_self" method="post" action="index.pl" name="set_filter">
    <select name="project" onChange='window.location="index.pl?project=" + this.value'>
        <option selected="selected"></option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
</form>
```

When I select an option (1) from the list, the url is set to `http://myserver.com/tests/index.pl?project=`

While on Google I get it right: `http://myserver.com/tests/index.pl?project=1`

Any ideas or alternatives?

Comment: Can you explain what `While on Google I get it right` represents?

Comment: <option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>

Comment: and your select tag isn't closed :)

Comment: The url that is displayed after redirection includes the vlaue from the select: ...index.pl?project=1 while on IE it's without the value.

Comment: some browsers read what is between <option></option> if they don't find value= inside the <option> some browsers doesn't but the right thing is to put value inside <option> as I stated in my comment above

Comment: OMG URGGGG so simple... :( yes adding the value to option solved it, outsmarted by Google T_T THANKS!

Comment: @WhiteLady and add the missing `</select>` too, won't hurt...

Comment: close your select tag too

Comment: Thanks CodeBird, it's closed, just missed it in the copy/paste here :)

Comment: Your code is perfectly [alright](http://jsfiddle.net/DLFLT/1/). I think the problem could be somewhere else.

Comment: @WhiteLady Based on your sample code my answer is correct and should be selected as the right answer to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `this.options[this.selectedIndex].text`

Comment: ... or (better) fix the html ;)

Comment: There is one problem with the code and that is the syntax to get a value from a select's option element. My answer shows the right way to do so, then one can use either ".value" or ".text" to get the actual value.